# adding an event listener to safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm trying to add an event listener, via JavaScript for the Safari browser because it doesn't recognize the unload event of a window, apparently.  So far I have:

```
function init()
{
//add unload event handler for safari
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari")!=-1) {
    bodyElt = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     if (bodyElt) {
      bodyElt.addEventListener("unload", onUnloadHandler, false);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Isn't it onunload vs. unload?

Comment: @shaun5 The first argument to `addEventListener()` needs to be the event *type*, which is `unload` here.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use browser sniffing.  The following is standards-compliant and works *everywhere* (if there is W3C DOM support; add wrappers as necessary):

```
    …

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function bodyLoad()
      {
        document.body.addEventListener("unload", onUnloadHandler, false);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="bodyLoad()">
    …
  </body>

…
```

Questions remain, though.  Why are you not using the `onunload` attribute of the `body` element in the first place?  And what do you need the `unload` event listener for?  Many people *think* they need `unload` listeners because they do not handle closures properly, or have that misguided idea of trying to keep visitors at their site.

Comment: Actually, I felt instantly guilty from your tone and loaded the code, IE throws errors document.body does not support addEventListener...

Comment: @flavour404 IE 9 in *Compatibility Mode* and IE < 9 does not support W3C DOM Level 2+ Events.  That is why I said "add wrappers as necessary".  One such wrapper would be [`jsx.dom.addEventListener()`](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fdom%2Fevents.js).

Comment: attachEvent instead of addEventListener is what you need in IE you mention erring.

Comment: @FSC No, please read “[addEvent() considered harmful](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html)”, also referred in my wrapper code.